# 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for .WithComCleanup()

Tags: .net, vsto, com-interop

Since upgrading a project from VS2010 to VS2012 I'm getting the error:

> 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for
>   .WithComCleanup())

When running this command line of code:

```
using (var cell = usedRange.Resource.Find(reservedWord, LookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, After: usedRange.Resource.Cells[usedRange.Resource.Rows.Count, usedRange.Resource.Columns.Count]).WithComCleanup())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I'd share the solution to this annoying problem, when executing the line in the intermediate window you get the tip:

> Embedded interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn' is
>   defined in both 'Excel.dll' and 'XYZ.ExcelAddin.ABC.dll'. Some
>   operations on objects of this type are not supported while debugging.
>   Consider casting this object to type 'dynamic' when debugging or
>   building with the 'Embed Interop Types' property set to false.

I solved the problem by turning **Embed Interop Types to False** for the reference DLL Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by turning `Embed Interop Types` to `False` for the reference DLL `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, but I get message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Не удается найти указанный файл."
```

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor when you build the project and see where Visual Studio is looking for the DLL. Either put the ref DLL where its expected or re-refeerence the correct DLL from the c:\Program Files\Office15\PIA folder.